# Create shortcut with minimized window

Tags: java

Good morning, I have a Java code using JShortcut, the problem is I can not create the shortcut with the minimized window, try looking for properties as windowstyle, but find nothing.

Code.

```
public void createDesktopShortcut() {

    try {
        link.setFolder(JShellLink.getDirectory("desktop"));
        link.setName("ie");
        link.setPath(filePath);
        //windowstyle = 7
        link.save();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

How can I add this option?

Comment: So you are trying to create a shortcut that opens the application minimized?

Comment: yes, but I can not add that option in java, in other languages ​​can using windowstyle in the properties of java shortcut but can not

Comment: I noticed the api has a get/set for shortcut arguments. You might create a shortcut with run as set to Minimized and call `getArguments() ` on that shortcut. Then you can see if there is anything there that you can set.

Comment: What argument i use ?

Comment: Use get arguments on a shortcut that already has the property set to open minimize (meaning create one manually and inspect with the lib). Then you can use that in the one you want to pragmatically create.